# Are there any enzymes synthesised by humans that specifically catalyse the hydrolysis of non-cyclic Imides?

Tags: metabolism, enzymes

Imides or dicarbonyl amides are an interesting class of compounds that includes the pharmaceuticals thalidomide, aniracetam and a few other drugs. These compounds, however, are cyclic and I'm wondering whether there's an enzyme found in the human body that specifically catalyses the degradation of non-cyclic imides. I'm thinking that fatty acid amide hydrolase (FAAH) may catalyse the hydrolysis of non-cyclic imides at least as a minor metabolic pathway.